# Updating Vuejs list

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel with vue I'd like to update my data in real-time (when new post/project) is published the main page add it (no refresh required)

## Question

1. How can I do that?

## code

`my component`

```
<div v-for="project in projects" :key="project.slug">
```

`my script`

```
<script>
import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
var moment = require('moment');
            
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                projects: {},
                app_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME,
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.load();
        },
        components: {
            pagination
        },
        methods: {
            //shorting projects body
            readMore: function (text, length, suffix) {
                return text.substring(0, length) + suffix;
            },
            //getting all projects
            load: function(page = 1) {
                Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {
                    moment
                });
                axios.get('/api/projects?page=' + page)
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.projects =  response.data.data;
                        // timing
                        Vue.filter('timeAgo', function(value){
                            return moment(value).fromNow();
                        });
                        //adding tooltip
                        Vue.nextTick(function () {
                            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                        });
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            },
            //numbers decimals
            formatPrice(value) {
                let val = (value/1).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',')
                return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

> sorry for part below (is just to be able to post this question
> **stackoverflow limitations**

.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into Websockets if you want the server to able to update the client of when there is new data.

The flow would be: new item added, Websocket from server sends this new item as json to all clients, client adds this item to the javascript list of items, vue auto updates the visible list to reflect this new item.

If websockets are impossible then you'll need to just run your load command on a short timer so it feels "real-time ish"

Comment: any code sample? none of this you said i can do with just idea :\

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting should be an okay place to start, assuming laravel

Comment: I tagged laravel and mentioned that i'm using laravel, the whole purpose for me to use vuejs was to avoid using echo and broadcasting so i can get such things with help of JavaScript language. `Thanks for the ideas anyway.`

Comment: No worries, sadly there's no way to get real-time data from the server without websockets. The closest you can get is just firing off your Ajax requests on a loop